# How can I calculate $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{n-k}$?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I would like to know if I can calculate a closed expression for
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{n-k}$$
This sum is equals to: $$1+(n-1)+(n-1)(n-2)+(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)+\ldots+(n-1)(n-2)/2+(n-1)$$

Comment: This is almost an entire row of Pascal's Triangle.

Comment: You forgot to divide the k-th term by k!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $$\sum_{k=1}^n {n-1 \choose n-k} = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose j}$$

Comment: Ok. So the sum is equal to $2^{n-1}$. Thanks.

Comment: Almost.  Don't forget about $k=n$.